# How long can prepared statements be used?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there any kind of time limit to how long prepared statements can be used?

Preparing a statement outside of a loop and then calling `execute()` from inside the loop provides a huge performance boost over preparing it every loop. However, what if a loop were to run for an hour or two? Could the statement prepared that long ago still be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of a prepared statement is guaranteed to last for a given session.
So if your session lasts an hour, the prepared statement will be valid for that hour.

The following statement is taken from this [link](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365244/Why-Prepared-Statements-are-important-and-how-to-use-them-properly):

`Normally, a prepared statement is associated with a single database connection. When the connection is closed, the preparedstatement is discarded.`

The keyword there is "normally".  If you want to read about the exceptions, follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're querying it within the loop it should run indefinitely, otherwise, alternatively if you're waiting for some event (i.e. a worker) it is dictated by `wait_timout`. You should catch any query errors such as [`CR_SERVER_GONE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) and retry your connection.